# CSS @keyframes translate3d Compatibility

Tags: css, compatibility

How do I specifically check for compatibility of `@keyframes translate3d animations` with the browser ?

**Please Don't close this question since I've tried many stackoverflow solutions before asking this question.**

*I want to check whether the browser my webpage runs is compatible for running animations, since many android browsers(Old Ones) are not capable of running them, they just stop displaying output text when animation fails (In MY Case). So, I would like to either stop animations or redirect them to another copy of my same website without any animations :)*

> **P.S** I've also tried using @supports, but of no use :(

```css
h1,h2{
            height: 40px;
            animation: an 1s ease-out 1 both;
        }
    @keyframes an {
        from {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(-35px, -40px, -150px) rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 35deg);
        }
        to {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1" class="th">Test Texts</h1>
<h2 id="h2" class="th">Also Test Texts..</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried [@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)? (It would be worth listing what you have tried, just so we don't waste peoples time looking at things you've ruled out)

Comment: I guess you have looked at https://caniuse.com/?search=translate3d. Please could you give more detail of what you are trying to do - show your code - as we can't tell from what you have told us what you may be trying to animate.

Comment: @DBS I've tried it, but of no use :(

Comment: CSS translate 3D and animations are supported all the way down to IE10... what browser are you thinking of supporting? IE10 and 11 do not have `@support` support tho, so you will probably need to use Modernizr to detect support. Then you can simply add those styles if support is detected.

Comment: @SimpleGuy_ Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@supports` query works just fine. It has to be at top level of the code. You also need to provide some dummy values for the `translate3d`.

```css
@supports(transform: translate3d(100px,100px,10px)){   
  div{
    background: blue;
  }
}

@supports not (transform: translate3d(100px,100px,10px)){   
  div{
    background: red;
  }
}

div{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
)
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

For browsers with no support for `@supports` query, you can add default value/property to the element. You also need to add `!important` to values of properties inside of `@supports` to override the default value.
This should work on all browsers.

```css
@supports(transform: translate3d(100px,100px,10px)){   
  div{
    background: blue !important;
  }
}

@supports not (transform: translate3d(100px,100px,10px)){   
  div{
    background: red !important;
  }
}

div{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;  /* default value */
)
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Applying this to your snippet, you get this:

```css
@supports(transform: translate3d(100px, 100px, 10px)) {
  h1,
  h2 {
    animation: an 1s ease-out 1 both !important;
  }
  @keyframes an {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(-35px, -40px, -150px) rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 35deg);
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }
}

@supports not (transform: translate3d(100px, 100px, 10px)) {
  h1,
  h2 {
    animation: an 1s ease-out 1 both !important;
    /*you can also set it to efault animation  */
  }
  @keyframes an {
    /* some different animation */
  }
}

h1,
h2 {
  height: 40px;
  animation: defaultA 1s ease-out 1 both;
}

@keyframes defaultA {
  /* some default animation */
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1" class="th">Test Texts</h1>
<h2 id="h2" class="th">Also Test Texts..</h2>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for browsers that support translate3d, but has no `@support` support, like IE10 and IE11.

Comment: @Terry Oh yes, I edited my answer. Please check

Comment: Bro Could you please edit the answer so that your answer seems to be matching with my code , since Iam a beginner ,Iam facing difficulties in the application of this, also I would like to add that last part of your answer (!important thing since I think the browser doesn't supports @supports (LOL) . So, If you could, could you please edit your answer so that it's applicable to h1 tags as given in my Question,Please :)

Comment: @SimpleGuy_ Please check

Answer (score 0):

Check with media query:

```
@media all and (-webkit-transform-3d) {
   css animation when supported
};
```

Check with @supports:

```
@supports (transform: translate3d) {

}
```

or

```
@supports not (transform: translate3d) {

}
```

or you can check out this javascript solution
https://gist.github.com/lorenzopolidori/3794226